# Mac OS X 10.6 Python 2.7 pytidylib utidylib could not find libtidy

Tags: python, htmltidy

I am answering my own question, but because I stayed up all night figuring it out, I will hopefully save others some pain. If you are getting either of the following messages after properly installing [pytidylib](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html) or [utidylib](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/utidylib), this answer may help.

Learning Python on Snow Leopard, I had installed the 32-bit version of Python 2.7 so that I could use the IDLE interpreter/editor. Stackoverflow has a great [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472349/what-are-the-differences-between-the-two-python-2-7-mac-os-x-disk-image-installer) why I had to do this.

When I installed utidylib, I got the following error from '`import tidy`':

'`OSError: Couldn't find libtidy, please make sure it is installed`.'

With pytidylib, I got this error when I tried '`from tidylib import tidy_document`':

'`OSError: Could not load libtidy using any of these names: libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy.`'

If you are getting these errors, please read this answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it looked like the Python packages could not find the files, what was really happening was that I compiled libtidy for the wrong architecture: x86_64 instead of i386. Using the 32-bit Python installer made them incompatible.

For neophytes like me, `lipo` will tell you the architecture of your files:

```
$ lipo -info /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Architectures in the fat file: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python are: ppc i386

$ lipo -info /usr/lib/libtidy.dylib
Non-fat file: /usr/lib/libtidy.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

You may have to locate your libtidy.dylib and python files to compare. To fix the problem, you have to re-compile libtidy for i386 (or link to an i386-compiled libtidy already on your system). To re-compile for i386, use [these instructions](http://bradjasper.com/blog/install-ulibtidy-on-mac-os-x.html) with the following modification:

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@tidy.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/tidy co -P tidy
cd tidy
sh build/gnuauto/setup.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr CFLAGS="-arch i386"
make && sudo make install
```

This worked for me. I hope it also works for you.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue (see stacktrace below) on Linux.
With pytidylib==0.2.1 installed with pip in a virtualenv on both Ubuntu 11.10 (Python 2.7) and Gentoo (Python 2.6).
Installing `apt-get install libtidy-dev` on Ubuntu and `emerge app-text/htmltidy` on Gentoo, solved it.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
File "/home/andre/Progz/some_site/djcode/apps/default/tests.py", line ?, in default.tests.__test__.doctest
Failed example:
    from tidylib import tidy_document
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/andre/Progz/some_site/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/_doctest.py", line 1267, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "", line 1, in 
        from tidylib import tidy_document
      File "/home/andre/Progz/some_site/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tidylib/__init__.py", line 71, in 
        raise OSError("Could not load libtidy using any of these names: %s" % (",".join(LIB_NAMES)))
    OSError: Could not load libtidy using any of these names: libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue.I installed tidylib,but still come out error as followed.

```
 raise OSError("Could not load libtidy using any of these names: %s" % (",".join(LIB_NAMES)))
    OSError: Could not load libtidy using any of these names: libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy
```

then I copy /usr/bin/tidy to my project folder ,and it got solved.